# Changing order of Coded UI test in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, vstest

I've been tasked with making our coded UI testing come out with passing tests (tests already created, just needed to adjust program code), but I'm having an interesting problem arise with some consistently failed tests. When I test these "failed" tests individually, they pass without any problems. I want to change the order of the tests to see if this can remedy the situation. The [TestInitializer] is set to start the program from the beginning, but isn't doing so when all the tests are running together on another machine with Windows Server 2012 using vstest.console.exe. I think if I can tinker with the order of the tests, I can at least bypass some of the fails that are happening. I see a *.orderedtest, but it doesn't seem to have all the tests that are being tested in there, so I'm not sure if that's the area to mess with. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have some thing like this to make it ordered

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyIntegratonTestLikeUnitTest()
{
        ScenarioA();

        ScenarioB();

    ....
}

private void ScenarioA()
{
     // Do your Stuff
}

private void ScenarioB()
{
     // Do your stuff
}
```

or Assign priority to each test like below

```
[TestMethod]
[Priority(1)]
{
     Code.
}

[TestMethod]
[Priority(2)]
{
    Code.
}

[TestMethod]
[Priority(3)]
{
    Code.
}
```